# php mail function with html not shown correct in exchange

Tags: php, email, exchange-server

I got a strange problem with php mail and exchange. When I use the a simple php html mailscript, see below (can be found all over internet) I see the mail as kind of plain text (see below) mail in Microsoft Exchange. But when I send the mail to an other account with Outlook I see the mail as a HTML-mail as it should be.

Doest anybody got a clue?

**Mailscript:**

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

**View in Exchange:**

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>
Subject:Birthday Reminders for August

Return-Path: root@server2.nedstars.nl
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 06 Oct 2010 13:39:59.0117 (UTC) FILETIME=[F839FBD0:01CB655B]

<html>
    <head>
      <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try replace the `"\r\n"` to `"\n"` in the headers

Comment: Ok, will try it when I get home.But strange thing is that it worked for 1.5 years,and yesterday it gave problems

Comment: what is the type of the machine that send the mail ?

Comment: It's a webserver that is hosted in the Netherlands

Comment: what i mean it is unix,  linux ? windows ? , some unix machines do problem with \r\n

Comment: The removal of "\r" fixed it, tnx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Content-Type` instead of `Content-type`? (capitalize the `type`)

Comment: Ok, will try it when I get home.But strange thing is that it worked for 1.5 years,and yesterday it gave problems